# AngularJS and Canvas not responding to changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

I'm creating an AngularJS 1.6 prototype and for one component I'm creating I need to use a HTML5 Canvas that will represent the data model, an array of players.

I've been able to make it work like a videogame (loop with update and draw calls) and it works correctly but today I wanted to show a list of players next to the canvas with a ng-repeat and it does not work.

By the tests I've done it seems that AngularJS is not aware of that push in the array and it does not refresh the DOM because if I do something else in the app that changes the DOM, then the list appears. What I'm doing wrong?

```
function TaggingPlaySituationController() {
    this.$onInit = function () {
        $ctrl.field.addEventListener("mousedown", $ctrl.mousedown, false);

        window.requestAnimationFrame($ctrl.loop);
    }

    this.mousedown = function (evt) {
        player = new Player($ctrl.resourceManager, $ctrl.mouse.x, $ctrl.mouse.y, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10));
        $ctrl.players.push(player);
    }

    this.loop = function () {
        var now = Date.now();
        var dt = now - $ctrl.lastUpdate;

        $ctrl.lastUpdate = now;

        $ctrl.update(dt);
        $ctrl.draw();
        window.requestAnimationFrame($ctrl.loop);
    };
}

function CanvasObject(resourceManager, x, y, width, heigth) {
    this.resourceManager = resourceManager;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function Player(resourceManager, x, y, dorsal) {
    CanvasObject.call(this, resourceManager, x, y, 18, 18);
    this.dorsal = dorsal;
}
Player.prototype = new CanvasObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found what was wrong. It was BASIC, but for that reason I've not seen it.

See this: `$ctrl.field.addEventListener("mousedown", $ctrl.mousedown, false);`

That's the problem, I've added to the canvas element `ng-mousedown="$ctrl.mousedown($event)"` and it's working as expected.